# Quickest way to store dataframes containing list fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a pandas dataframe that contains 3 fields:

- Id field (ex. 1234)
- text field (ex. "some text")
- list field (ex. ['som', 'ome', 'tex', 'ext'])

When using `pd.DataFrame.to_csv()`, the list column is stored as a literal and must be re-converted when loading back into memory. Because the table has over 3 million rows, this takes upwards of 30 min when using the loading process `pd.read_csv(path, encoding='latin-1', converters={'list_field':eval})`.

I have tried using pandas' [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) function to give each list element its own row, save the exploded table, and then aggregate using `pd.DataFrame.group_by()` upon loading, but this seemed to take significantly longer.

I have also considered `json.dump() / load()` or `pickle` but my understanding is that these packages also store lists as literals and must be converted upon loading.

Is there an efficient/quick way of doing this **to reduce the load time** of the dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried `df.to_pickle('data.pkl')` and then `df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely after running some tests, I can confirm this takes the same amount of time to load the pickle files.